# Aid in finding uninstantiated variables in a function in PHP?

Tags: php, refactoring

I'm refactoring some monolithic code by breaking it up unto function. Since the variables were always in scope in the procedural section, I'm often finding a variable that I overlooked and neglected to pass in to the function that I've migrated its code to. Is there anything that can aid me in finding uninstantiated variables in the function? A feature in an IDE, perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

The php code validator in eclipse/PDT is pretty good at this.  It will highlight lines with errors; hovering the mouse over the error marker will pop up why it thinks there's an error.